# WSO2 3.2.0 API Manager Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: ssl, openssl, wso2, ssl-certificate, api-manager

I'm getting the following error ssl: handshake_failure on wso2 api manager 3.2.0 when call the api. I added the certificates using keytool. The below are the instruction that I used to add the certs

```
What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]: axis2a.backend.mytest
What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]: apim
What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]: wso2
What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]: colombo
What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]: A
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]: LK
Is CN=axis2a.backend.mytest, OU=apim, O=wso2, L=colombo, ST=A, C=LK correct?
[no]: yes

keytool -export -alias wso2am -file wso2am.crt -keystore wso2carbon.jks -storepass wso2carbon

keytool -import -alias wso2am -file wso2am.crt -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
```

I'm get the following error when I call the api

```
 ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666) ~[?:1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the Java JDK version in this environment?

Comment: ```jdk1.8.0_111```